# Sorting an array of objects (Outputting data but not in order)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

This is a shortened version of some data that is returned:

```
var array = 
[{
    "response":
        {
            "itineraries":[
            {
                "price":
                {
                    "totalPricePerPassenger":"104"
                }
            },
            {
                "price":
                {
                    "totalPricePerPassenger":"102"
                }
            },
            {
                "price":
                {
                    "totalPricePerPassenger":"103"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
}];
```

My plan is to sort the data that is returned by the total price.

Here is the code that I am using to sort and display the result:

```
function sort(a, b){
    var a_price = a.response.itineraries.price.totalPricePerPassenger();
    var b_price = b.response.itineraries.price.totalPricePerPassenger(); 
    return ((a_price < b_price) ? -1 : ((a_price > b_price) ? 1 : 0));
}

var data = array.sort(sort); 
console.log(data);
```

From the console.log above this is the result that it outputs, as you can see the prices are still in their original order and have no changed.

[image: Console.log output]

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Am I on the right track?

Comment: totalPricePerPassenger why you are using it like a function. Try without ();

Comment: Not sure how I missed that one, oops. That and the answer below seemed to fix it for this example but not for the live API response...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sort(a, b){
    var a_price = a.price.totalPricePerPassenger;
    var b_price = b.price.totalPricePerPassenger; 
    return ((a_price < b_price) ? -1 : ((a_price > b_price) ? 1 : 0));
}

var data = array[0].response.itineraries.sort(sort); 
console.log(data);
```

You were sorting the outer array, not the inner array.  Doing it this way returns the inner array to data, but you can also just pass array directly, since the sort happens "in place"

Comment: This works great with the example I had given above but as soon as I took it into the live API response I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined '. :(

Edit: I tried JQuery makeArray and then did a little instanceOf to see if it was an array and it said it was, but still nothing.

Comment: Well this solution is tailored to the data above.  If the real data is different then you'll need to adjust accordingly.  The overall concept here is to sort at the level of the array.  So figure out what the structure of the object is and drill down to the array and sort that